# замена строки с неизвесными символами | php

Tags: php, замена

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать как такое
реализовать:

Есть строка в которой содержится примерно такой
текст "ABCDEFDKWHCGSN" (14 символов) первые 2
символа извесны, остальные нет и нужно заменить
всю эту строку с 12 неизвесными символами на
правильную строку "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" регистр не
особо важен, есть такой код у кого нибудь?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Есть возможность замены с помощью регулярных выражений. Конкретно - preg_replace().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace("/ab[a-z]{12}/i", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", $input);
```

Comment: А с цифрами то-же самое? (я про поиск и замену чисел)

Comment: @ФедорАлексеев в целом наподобие того. зависит от конкретной задачи